# gson: ignore inner json

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I need to extract inner json as string. Using Gson. And it failed.

```
public class PagenatedJSON {
    @SerializedName("content")
    @Expose
    private List<String> content;
    
    @SerializedName("totalPages")
    @Expose
    private Long totalPages;
    
    @SerializedName("number")
    @Expose
    private Long number; // num of page
}
```

So, there are complex unknown inner class "Content". And i need to get it as STRING. So it needn't any parse. But gson try to do it: `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 14 path $.content[0]`

How to ignore inner parsing?

Comment: You should add the actual JSON to your question.

Comment: According to what rule do you want to have an inner JSON structure as a string? There is no default behavior for that!

Comment: To achieve that, the client sending the JSON needs to format it accordingly. What you may currently have is: {'content':{...}}. Instead, what the client should send then: {'content':"{...}"}.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, why? It must by common solution to use with any data.

Comment: @sbsatter, i can't edit input json. And i won't to edit it - if someone need to use it as nested json he can do that.

Comment: Is there're no solution to effect on gson behavior?

Comment: @AntispamAntispam well of course you can dive deep and modify how your json is parsed. In fact you can change the serialization/deserialization mechanism all by yourself including considering logic appropriate for your case. But not worth the hassle. In your case, I suggest using a List<Map<String, Object>> content; to get the object, and on receiving the object in your controller/service, do a gson.toString(content);

Comment: @sbsatter, wow, it sounds like a solution. But why we should cast to Map, not to Object? So, use `private List<Object> content;` to cast as java-object, and re-cast it to srting. Isn't it?

Comment: That too work since it's the same thing, any json object will be kept as a map underneath. Probably LinkedHashMap (haven't used recently).

Comment: A JSON file is intended to represent a hierarchy of objects, arrays, and elements in them. If the intention is that one of the element is a string rather than an object, it should not be represented as an object in JSON but as a string. Changing the logic of JSON is possible, but no, it isn't a common thing to do, and there is no simple solution for it. If you have a JSON that **misrepresents** the data, then you have to write custom code to parse it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to solve my issue is set type of "Content" as Object (`private List<Object> content;`).
It parse without errors and get serializable variable - so it could convert back into String.

But it have side effects: number types could be recognized wrong.

Comment: Thanks @sbsatte for this decision.